# Check whether mail.domain.com is POP or IMAP

Tags: java, android, imap, pop3

How to check whether server uses POP or IMAP protocol?
It is not mentioned in mail.domain.com, but it is accessible.
I would like to check which protocol mailserver uses without downloading any data from it, when I know both username and password for that mail server.

Comment: Simply try connecting with either protocol?

Comment: The only way to try is to connect to the respective ports (110 and 143).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some servers provide this information using DNS SRV records, as described in [RFC 6186 - Use of SRV Records for Locating Email Submission/Access Services](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6186).  You could look up the SRV record for `_imap._tcp.domain.com`, `_imaps._tcp.domain.com`, `_pop3._tcp.domain.com` and `_pop3s._tcp.domain.com`, and see which ones are present.

You can try this from the command line using the `dig` utility.  For example, to see what services Gmail offers:

```
$ dig +short -t SRV _imap._tcp.gmail.com
0 0 0 .

$ dig +short -t SRV _imaps._tcp.gmail.com
5 0 993 imap.gmail.com.

$ dig +short -t SRV _pop3._tcp.gmail.com
0 0 0 .

$ dig +short -t SRV _pop3s._tcp.gmail.com
20 0 995 pop.gmail.com.
```

The first two numbers in the result are priority and weight, which we can ignore if there's only one answer.  The third number is the port number, and the final value is the domain name.  `0 .` is a special value to indicate that the service is not offered, so from the above results we see that:

- Gmail does not offer unencrypted IMAP access.
- Gmail offers encrypted IMAP access on port 993 of host `imap.gmail.com`.
- Gmail does not offer unencrypted POP3 access.
- Gmail offers encrypted POP3 access on port 995 of host `pop.gmail.com`.

---

However, most servers don't bother setting up DNS SRV records for email, so most of the time your only chance is to try connecting and see if the server answers.